# jqplot chart with multiple line based on same Date or Time

Tags: jqplot, linechart

I have the following data and i want to plot them with jqplot on line-chart with 2 lines.

```
series:[Time  Value1 Value2] 
      [13:51 22.875 9.275]
```

What I am looking for is a Chat with
 **XAxis:Time
 L1:[Yaxis1:Value1] 
 L2:[Yaxis2:Value2]**.

I can fairly change  data structure *into  [Time Value1] and [Time Value2]* or any other kind
But It is important to plot them both in one chart together.
Could you please write the scratch of the code or refer me to a proper example ?
Thank you

Comment: You want a line chart with two lines and a DateAxisRenderer?  Did you look at the exmples on the jqPlot website?  Did you try and code this yourself before asking for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'multiple ticks for the same date' for the date-axis can be solved by including the following code snippet:

```
xaxis: { label: "Whatever you name it", renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,       min:dateVal[0], max:dateVal[dateVal.length-1], tickInterval: '1 day',
```

Please include min,max and tickInterval under 'xaxis:' and not under 'tickOptions:' . In my case i am having the date values in the array dateVal where the 0th element is the minimum value of date for the x-axis and the last element is the max date value. If you so wish you could hard-code the date values.

I hope this will be of help.

Answer (score 7):

It's actually very easy. You define an array of values for each data line:

```
var line1 = [[date1, val1], [date2, val2]];
var line2 = [[date1, val11], [date2, val12]];
var plot = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1, line2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the time values are the same, you can do

```
var line1 = [val1_1, val1_2];
var line2 = [val2_1, val2_2];
var ticks = [time1, time2]
var plot = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1, line2], {
    xaxis: { ticks: ticks }
});
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not seem to work when the x-axis ticks are dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179346/jqplot-separating-ticks-and-series-values