# jqplot: Separating ticks and series values

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a web service that sends date values (for x-axis) in one array. It sends y-axis values in another array.

Is it possible to have jqPlot create a chart with 2 such arrays. Documentation seems to indicate this is possible.

I know combining the date and series value in one array works. Would like to avoid the extra processing of combining the 2 arrays.

This jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abhivm/HmnmH/1/ shows sample code. Can anyone please look and let me know how to do this?

jsFiddle is returning errors this morning, so posting the jQuery code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dateValues = ["01/15/2012", "01/17/2012", "01/18/2012", "01/19/2012"];
    var dailyValues = [219, 73, 73, 146];

    plot2 = $.jqplot('chart', [dailyValues], {

        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                ticks: dateValues
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks
Abhi

Comment: Same problem, I've got 5 series, all with the same x-axis dates, seems a shame to repeat the first series [date1, y1-val1] [ date2, y1-val2]... and then for the 2nd series [date1, y2-val1] [ date2, y2-val2]... but using ticks:dateValues and the DateAxisRenderer just produce a blank chart. Interestingly, the y-axis scale is computed correctly, and the x-axis is showing ok. It's just there's no line drawn.

Answer (score 1):

I can not figure out a way for jqPlot to accept how you want to define your inputs (the ticks option seems to only work with numbers).  I'm curious as to the "avoid the extra processing" comment.  With jQuery it would be as easy as:

```
$.map(dateValues, 
       function(val,idx){
           return [[val,dailyValues[idx]]];
       }
);
```

to "merge" the two arrays into point pairs.

Comment: Mark, agreed $.map is a quick way to do the merge. I want avoid writing any more lines of Javascript, keeping it as small as possible. Since the documentation suggests ticks and series can be supplied independently, I was hoping to use that short cut. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'multiple ticks for the same date' for the date-axis can be solved by including the following code snippet:

```
  xaxis: {
           label: "Whatever you name it",
           renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
           min:dateVal[0],
           max:dateVal[dateVal.length-1],
           tickInterval: '1 day',
```

Please include min,max and tickInterval under `xaxis:` and not under `tickOptions:` .

In my case I am having the date values in the array dateVal where the 0th element is the minimum value of date for the x-axis and the last element is the max date value. If you so wish you could hard-code the date values.

I hope this will be of help.