# graphing multiple series with same x value and different y values

Tags: jqplot

When graphing multiple series all with the same x value and different y values using jqplot, is there a way to specify the x values only ones.  For example, if I'm graphing two series, I can supply data to jqplot like this:

```
 [[[2014-1-2, 25], [2014-1-3, 26], [2014-1-4, 27]], [[2014-1-2, 45], [2014-1-3, 47], [2014-1-4, 48]]]
```

These two series have the same x values and different y values, and I'm specifying the x values twice.  Is there a format that allows me to only specify the x values one time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqplot: Separating ticks and series values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179346/jqplot-separating-ticks-and-series-values)